# Мой код работает? (localStorage, onload, unload)

Tags: javascript

Мой код работает? Не могу понять. Вроде нет, но может я неправильно проверяю.

```js
var progressLine = document.getElementById('progressLine');
localStorage.setItem('progressLineNumberLocal', progressLine.value);

function plus1() {
    progressLine.value += 1;
}

function plus5() {
    progressLine.value += 5;
}

function minus1() {
    progressLine.value -= 1;
}

function minus5() {
    progressLine.value -= 5;
}

function fun1() {
    progressLine.value = localStorage.getItem('progressLineNumberLocal');
}

function fun2() {
    localStorage.setItem('progressLineNumberLocal', progressLine.value);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>
            Document
        </title>
    </head>
    <body onload="fun1()" unload='fun2()'>
        <button id='but1' onclick="plus1()">+1</button>
        <button id='but2' onclick="plus5()">+5</button>
        <button id='but3' onclick="minus1()">-1</button>
        <button id='but4' onclick="minus5()">-5</button>
        <br>
        <progress min='0' max='100' value='0' id='progressLine'></progress>
        <script src='script.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

И как починить? Я думаю вы поняли смысл кода тут кнопки по увеличению и уменьшению чисел в PROGRESS(и это работает), но я хочу чтобы когда ты набрал допустим 50 в полоске и вышел с сайта. После захода на него в другой раз у тебя уже тут было 50 набрано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var progressLine; // = document.getElementById('progressLine');
//localStorage.setItem('progressLineNumberLocal', progressLine.value);
function fun1() {
  progressLine = document.getElementById('progressLine');
  progressLine.value = localStorage.getItem('progressLineNumberLocal');
}

<body onload="fun1()" onunload='fun2()'>
```